# ExtJs 3: Tab keyup event in grid

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I try to catch Tab key up vent in extjs grid. but i can't catch keyup event in extjs grid this is my code.

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel, {
   initEvents : function(){
      Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel.superclass.initEvents.call(this); 
      this.addListener('keyup', function() {
         alert('key');
      });
}
```

please tell what i did wrong with this above code?

Answer (score 0):

[Document](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel-event-keypress) shows only keydown and keypress events, have you tried those?